# Algorithm to check for a linear sum to zero

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

Given a list of `N` non-negative integers, propose an algorithm to check if the sum of `X` numbers from the list equals the remaining `N-X`.

In other words, a simpler case of the [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which involves the entire set.

**An attempted solution**

Sort the elements of the list in descending order. Initialize a variable `SUM` to the first element. Remove first element (largest, `a(1)`). Let `a(n)` denote the `n-th` element in current list.

While list has more than one element,

1. Make `SUM` equal to `SUM + a(1)` or `SUM - a(1)`, whichever is closest to `a(2)`. (where closest means `|a(2) - SUM_POSSIBLE|` is minimum).
2. Remove `a(1)`.

If the `SUM` equals `-a(1)` or `a(1)`, there exists a linear sum.

**The problem**

I cannot seem to resolve above algorithm, if it is correct, I would like a proof.
If it is wrong (more likely), is there a way to get this done in linear time?

PS: If I'm doing something wrong please forgive :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you want the sum of `x` numbers to be equal to the sum of the other `N-x` numbers.
You can simplify this by saying you want to see if there's a subset which sums up to `S/2` where `S` is the total sum of the whole set.

So, you can calculate the Sum you need to get to with one iteration (**O(n)**).

Then just use a known algorithm like **[Knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)** to find a subset that meets your sum.

Another more "mathematical" explanation: **[Dynamic Programming – 3 : Subset Sum](https://tkramesh.wordpress.com/tag/subset-sum/)**

Edit:

As an answer to your other question, your algorithm is wrong. consider this list of numbers:

{3,3,4,4}

The total sum is 14, so you're looking for a subset with the sum of 7. Obviously it will be 3+4.

Your algorithm will return false after examining the 2 3's

Comment: I think you missed the sorting part. `{3,3,4,4}` -> `{4,4,3,3}`, which would correctly pick `4-4=0` over `4+4=7` as `|0-3|=3 < |7-3|=4`. The proposed algorithm can be now be called on remainder of the list.

The other part of your answer I understand, but I think the algorithm I proposed would be faster (if proven correct). Thanks for the lightning fast responses!

Comment: I just saw [Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) which is exactly what we're trying to do once we find `S` is even. As a bonus, my algorithm breaks on the greedy counter-example as well. A final thank you to Yochai :D